# What type of code\decode method used by Haxe?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, decode, haxe

http://haxe.org/api/haxe/crypto/basecode There are some information, I need to find analog in Delphi or something . Allows to encode/decode String and bytes using a power of two base dictionary. Its not Base 64, because it used something like key.

Example of usion in JS:
( Where b = encoded data )

```
var c = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
b = haxe.BaseCode.decode(b, c)
```

Comment: It is base-64 and "key" is simply how the values 0..63 are mapped accordingly (there are many different base-64 mappings). encode does not add any padding. Despite being in "crypto", it is *not* an encryption scheme.

Comment: Can you share link or some more information about that?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/haxe/source/browse/trunk/std/haxe/crypto/BaseCode.hx?r=5844 - the trivial loop mapping can be seen in `encodeBytes`. It is base-64 (without padding) because the key size is 64. (It would also encode base2/8/16/32/128 if asked.)

Comment: And what cipher or what i should use to decode it in delphi ?

Comment: Use [base-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), as stated above. Find a base-64 Delphi implementation and use it. You may need to add padding (as discussed in the linked resource) or replace characters in the input string depending on how the Delphi implementation works.